# How to get permission to see the file system in BlackBerry simulator?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

My app is creating some files. I want to see these files in file system of my device or simulator. Can I get access to file system?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see them in the file browser on the device/simulator? Or are you trying to do this in your app?

Comment: waiting for your response please see the comment of jprofitt and give some more information...

Comment: simulators of devices that support SD cards allow you to designate a local folder on your development machine to hold the contents of the virtual SD card. You could then use Windows Explorer to watch the folder you choose.

Comment: I want to see them in the file browser.